# For any point x on the Earth (or any sphere really) the antipode, often written as −x, is the point exactly on the other side.

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I know this is like an easier version proof of Borsuk–Ulam theorem. However, the proof to Borsuk–Ulam theorem is a little bit difficult for me to follow.

Comment: What’s the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $e$ is the equator, consider the function $$D : e \to \Bbb R, \qquad D(x) := T(x) - T(-x) .$$ By definition, it suffices to show that $D$ has a zero.

Answer (score 0):

$D(x)=T(x)-T(-x)$ is a continuous function on $x\in E \text{ (equator)}. $ If $\exists x\in E$ such that $D(x)=0$ we are done. If not then $D(x)\neq 0$. Wlog, $D(x)>0.$ Then $D(-x)<0$ gives that there is a point $x_0$ on $E$ such that $D(x_0)=0$ and hence $T(x_0)=T(-x_0).$